# django-import-export to export User model

Tags: django, django-admin, django-import-export

I'm using the django-import-export library with success to provide a data download option via the django admin for some of my defined models.

I'm having difficulty however providing the same export option via the User Admin.

For my other models I've done something like the following to my `admin.py`:

```
class OtherResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Other

class OtherAdmin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    # Other admin definition here
```

My problem is providing the same Export functionality to pre-packaged Django models like `User`.

I tried the following...

```
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User

class UserAdmin(ExportMixin, UserAdmin):
    pass
```

But this has a couple problems,

1. It drops a bunch of the `User` model fields from the list display (like `is_active` and `groups`)
2. I can see that something is not fully connected because adding `exclude`'s to the UserResource is not excluding those fields from the export

I could re-create the `UserAdmin` on my end, but I'm hoping (and guessing) that's unnecessary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So I was making a couple of mistakes.

1. I was being an idiot (I was importing the django UserAdmin rather than the UserAdmin I had created as an override a couple years ago in a dependency to this project -- this explains why fields were dropped when overriding the UserAdmin)
2. I was failing to manually link the OtherResource to the OtherAdmin as explained in the [django-import-export docs](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting_started.html#admin-integration)

The solution to both of the above code samples is as follows:

For the `Other` model

```
class OtherResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Other

class OtherAdmin(ExportMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    resource_class = OtherResource
    # Other admin definition here
```

and for the `User` model

```
class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

class UserAdmin(ExportMixin, UserAdmin):
    resource_class = UserResource
    pass

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Viola.
Everything works as intended.
`Other` model is exported in full.
`User` model is exported as 3 columns (first name, last name, and email).

Answer (score 2):

if you want to import export in user models in Django then override this code in your application admin.py

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ExportMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin

# Register your models here.


class UserResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email')

# class UserAdmin(ExportMixin, UserAdmin):
#     resource_class = UserResource
#     pass

class UserAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id','username','first_name', 'last_name', 'email')
    # list_filter = ('created_at',)
    resource_class = UserResource
    pass



admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Imports required

```
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ExportMixin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
```