# Can not import without id

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

**Software:**
Python3.6.2
Django1.11
django-import-export==0.5.1
OSX10.12.6

**INSTALLED_APPS:**

```
THIRD_PARTY_APPS = [
    ...,
    'reversion',       # django-reversion
    'import_export',   # django-import-export
]
```

**Requirements:**
1. Model has `reversion`
2. Model can be able to do `import`
3. Each imported role has uploader as `created_user`, and `updated_user`
(However, just for now I let it read from the Excel file and here it is the problem)

**Attempts:**
1. Since 2 of the requirements will hit hard with strict `meta` class. Then I apply `reichert` solution https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion/issues/323
2. [image]
[image]

**Problem:**

```
Line number: 1 - get() keywords must be strings
None, 696 02, Lane, Ronald Regan, Ratíškovice, n/a, Dolichitus patagonum, admin, admin
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/soken/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 434, in import_row
instance, new = self.get_or_init_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/soken/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 258, in get_or_init_instance
instance = self.get_instance(instance_loader, row)
File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/soken/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/resources.py", line 252, in get_instance
return instance_loader.get_instance(row)
File "/Users/el/.pyenv/versions/soken/lib/python3.6/site-packages/import_export/instance_loaders.py", line 33, in get_instance
return self.get_queryset().get(**params)
TypeError: get() keywords must be strings
```

**Question:**
What should I do next?

**Models:**
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/98e641d57c5de3394f816a5d9b80ef13

**admin.py**
https://gist.github.com/elcolie/081017adc7b5e2fd7a3a38b0573597c6

**References:**
[Dealing with import of foreignKeys in django-import-export](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697797/dealing-with-import-of-foreignkeys-in-django-import-export)
[django-import-export to export User model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28886074/django-import-export-to-export-user-model)
[Django Import/Export to multiple Models (foreignkey)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32197345/django-import-export-to-multiple-models-foreignkey)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is I have to expose `id` field to the file :(

```
ZIPCODE_BASIC_FIELDS = [
    'id',  # Add 
    'zipcode',
    'region',
    'prefecture',
    'city',
    'town',
    'building',
]

class ZIPCodeAddressResource(resources.ModelResource):
    zipcode = fields.Field(widget=widgets.CharWidget())
    created_user = fields.Field(column_name='created_user', attribute='created_user', widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(User, 'username'))
    updated_user = fields.Field(column_name='updated_user', attribute='updated_user', widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(User, 'username'))

    class Meta:
        model = ZIPCodeAddressImportExport
        # exclude = ['id', ]  # Need to remove this line
        fields = IMPORT_COLUMNS
        skip_unchanged = True
        report_skipped = True
        import_id_fields = ['id', ] # Let it had 'id'
        export_order = IMPORT_COLUMNS
```

Answer (score 0):

See this Answer, It will exclude your ID and also you can include any Foreign key if you want to 
[Exclude id from import in Django import-export Csv](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53639034/5654518)